How can I implement TensorFlow SSD (Object Detection) to work with MRTK 3 XR Rig
I'm trying to get a Unity Android AR project running with AR Foundation, AR Core and MRTK 3 with TensorFlow SSD.
I used the sample for this.
In the sample scene it works great, but as soon as I add an MRTK XR rig and use the camera from it, the object recognition stops and the green hitbox and the UI elements flicker around.
I have tested the XR Rig from Unity and tried to port the XR Rig into the given scene. Both attempts failed.
Unity 2023.2.15
